# Mysql : update query syntax incorrect

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute this query but I am getting an error.

```
update T_CLIENT c set taxe_income = true
where c.id in (select c1.id from T_CLIENT c1, T_ADRESS a
where c1.id = a.client_id and a.country_id = 14  and a.adress_principale is true);
```

The error is :

> You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause

I don't know how to write this query in order to make it work.
If anyone has an idea...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
update T_CLIENT c inner join T_ADRESS a on c.id = a.client_id 
set taxe_income = true
where a.country_id = 14  and a.adress_principale is true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET col = (
  SELECT ... FROM (SELECT.... FROM) AS t);
```

**You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.** as stated [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need join for this question;

**1. way**

```
update T_CLIENT c,T_ADRESS a  set c.taxe_income = true
    where c.id = a.client_id 
    and a.country_id = 14  
    and a.adress_principale is true
```

**2. way**

```
UPDATE T_CLIENT
SET T_CLIENT.taxe_income  = true
    FROM T_CLIENT c,T_ADRESS a
        WHERE c.id = a.client_id 
        and a.country_id = 14  
        and a.adress_principale is true
```

Comment: 1. way updates 39 record and 2.way syntax seems to be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to use an alias for your subquery :

```
update T_CLIENT c set taxe_income = true
where c.id in (
    (
    select c1.id from T_CLIENT c1, T_ADRESS a
    where c1.id = a.client_id and a.country_id = 14  and a.adress_principale is true
    ) as tmptable
);
```

For more information, read this : [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: "as tmptable" seems to be a syntax error for mysqlworkbench

Comment: TEMPTABLE is a keyword in MySQL, but tmptable is not. I don't know why you have this syntax error...